# ParseException when parsing a date of yyyy-MM-dd format

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, date-parsing, unparseable

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
Date date = dateFormatMonth.parse(strtdate[0]);
```

`strdate[0]` contains "2018-06-11"

I'm getting a unparsable exception on this line:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-06-11"

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: `LocalDate.parse(strtdate[0])`. Since your date string conforms with the ISO 8601 standard, no explicit formatter is needed. So there’ll be no chance of specifying an incorrect format. Also the modern `LocalDate` is a date without time of day, which clearly seems to match your requirements better (a `Date` despite its name is a point in time).

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because you are using the wrong pattern to parse the date. Use this instead:

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
Date date = dateFormatMonth.parse(strtdate[0]);
```

Assuming "06" is the month and "11" is day.